# Python list of words from a file with a specific length * no punctuation included in the words

Tags: python, string, list, file

Result should be: a list of words with a length bigger than 9 , words should be lower and no punctuation in words, ***only three lines of code in the body of the function.
The problem in my code is that is still adding punctuation to my word. I tried with checking just for one exmp. if ch not in one of those ->('-' or '"' or '!') or with r'[.,"!-]'.

I also tried to open the file not using with and it worked, i got the result that i want but using this method i am not gonna respect the part with only 3 lines of code inside body function

```py
import string
min_length = 9
with open('my_file.txt') as file:

    content = ''.join([ch for ch in file if ch not in string.punctuation])
    result = [word.lower() for word in content.split() if len(word)>min_length]


print(result)
'''my output:
['distinctly', 'repeating,', 'entreating', 'entreating', 'hesitating', 'forgiveness', 'wondering,', 'whispered,', '"lenore!"-', 'countenance', '"nevermore."', 'sculptured', '"nevermore."', 'fluttered-', '"nevermore."', '"doubtless,"', 'unmerciful', 'melancholy', 'nevermore\'."', '"nevermore."', 'expressing', 'nevermore!', '"nevermore."', '"prophet!"', 'undaunted,', 'enchanted-', '"nevermore."', '"prophet!"', '"nevermore."', 'upstarting-', 'loneliness', 'unbroken!-', '"nevermore."', 'nevermore!']
```

as you can see there are still words with punctuation

Comment: What is your input data.

Comment: The input is a file.txt with a song centered or a poem :D

Comment: can I assume you file data is `['distinctly', 'repea!ting,', 'entr!eating', '!entreating', 'hesitati-ng!', '!forgiveness', 'wonderin!g,', 'whisper!ed,', '"lenore!"-', 'coun!tenance', '"nevermor-e."']`

Comment: ```    Deep into that darkness peering, long I stood there wondering,
        fearing,
  Doubting, dreaming dreams no mortals ever dared to dream before;
    But the silence was unbroken, and the stillness gave no token,
    And the only word there spoken was the whispered word, "Lenore!"
  This I whispered, and an echo murmured back the word, "Lenore!"-
                Merely this, and nothing more.``` this is a part from my data

Answer (score 0):

I got this.

```py
from string import punctuation
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n','')


for a in punctuation:
    data = data.replace(a,'')

data = list(set([a for a in data.split(' ') if len(a)>9]))
print(data)
```

output:

```py
There is an empty list because in the given data there not a single word which has more than 9 letters.
```

Comment: even tho it works there are more than 3 lines of code, i need max 3

Comment: @GeorgeAnghel114 including imports this is not possible.

Comment: i checked your code vs the one that i am refactoring to see the output and yours adds \n or \n\n at the end of each word in the list plus your method make duplicates in the list

Comment: @GeorgeAnghel114 can you give those words which have more than 9 letters.

Comment: you can check for length of 3 or 4 for the paragraph that i wrote it above

Comment: i check for len(a)>10 the correct output: ['forgiveness', 'countenance'], your output: ['forgiveness', 'upstarting\n', 'nevermore\n\n', 'Nevermore\n\n', 'expressing\n', 'countenance'] the only problem in this case are the \ and n

Comment: it's perfect sir! but the next step is to write only 3 lines of code which that part with data = f.read().replace('\n','') makes it complicated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be an appropriate solution:

```python
from string import punctuation

with open('files/text.txt') as f:

    print(set([a for a in f.read().translate(''.maketrans('', '', ''.join([ p for p in punctuation ]) + '\n')).split(' ') if len(a)>9]))
```

However this is a crime against humanity in terms of readability and I would highly suggest you relax this three line requirement to allow your code to be more understandable in the long run.